# working of operators in while loop(c programming)

Tags: c, while-loop, operator-keyword

I am beginner to c programming. Hope you guys can help me.

```
i=0;
while(i++<12)
printf("%d\n",i);
```

My question not regarding operators or how the code works. I have checked various forms so i know what this piece of code does and the final value in i will be 13. What I want to know is this:

From my perspective operators must follow operator priority(preference). So ++ must be evaluated before <. 
Operator priority link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-operator-precedence-associativity/

lets i=3 for now,

```
Step 1:while(i++<12)
Step 2:while((i+1)<12)
Step 3:while(4<12)
Step 4:true and enters while loop
```

If operator preference is neglected(but I don't know why):

```
Step 1:while(i++<12)
Step 2:while(i<12)
Step 3:while(3<12) which returns value 1
Step 4:while(1++) operator ++ on the return value 1 from above step
Step 5:while(2) which is true and enters while loop
```

I hope you guys can understand my question. Please help.

Comment: You really need to study C. `1=0` does not make any sense, whatsoever.

Comment: "First i>12 will be checked to return value 1. Then ++(increment operator) must be performed on the return value '1' "  I don't understand what you mean here. Do you mean that the > check returns value 1 or that i++ returns value 1? Where did you get 2 from?

Comment: is that `1=0` a typo for `i=0`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I am beginner for the forums. I will try to not make mistakes again

Comment: I mean that < returns the value 1 and ++ will be operated on the value returned by < which in this case is 1.

Comment: No, `i++` means that `i` is incremented after the comparison `i < 12`.

Comment: can you tell me the reason why i is incremented after comparing of i<12? because if you go with operator priority in c first we must go with ++ then <. This is what is bugging me.

Comment: The operator priority isn't about the order of execution, it's about what they attach to, or where you write the parentheses. The `++` attaches to the `i` because there are no other options in this case, but if you'd had the equivalent `12>i++`, then `++` would still attach to `i` instead of the full `12>i` expression. That is, the table tells you that `12>i++` means `12 > (i++)`, not `(12>i) ++`. Again, in your original, the `++` attaches to `i` because there's no other expression available it could be connected to and precedence doesn't matter.

Comment: @KRISHNAI because the language says so, that is what the syntax means. Variable `i` is compared and then incremented. It is called *post-increment* as dictinct from `++i` where `i` is incremented before the comparison: *pre-increment*.

Comment: Thanks Daniel H, You have got me corrected. Thanks guys for all the help because everyone of your answers helpful to further improve my understanding of c language.

Comment: oops! I forgot one final question. while(i++<12): why isn't i incremented first before < comparison. As I have mentioned as per operator preference order ++ takes priority <.

Comment: precedence* not preference

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
i = 0;
while(i<12)       //compare i with 12
    printf("%d\n",i);

i = 0; 
while(i++<12)        //compare i with 12 and THEN i=i+1
    printf("%d\n",i);

i = 0;
while(++i<12)        //first i=i+1 and then compare i with 12
    printf("%d\n",i);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I know the procedure you explained. What I want to say is: while(i++<12) is in the code I expected that both ++ and < will be evaluated before passing the value to while.